# Which is correct vs which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

When using the word "**which**" is it necessary to still use "**one**" after asking a question or do "**which**" and "**which one**" have the same meaning? Where do you draw the line on the difference between "**which**" and "**which one**" when asking a question that involves more than one answer?

**Example:**

**How much is 1 + 1?**

> **Which** *(one)* is the right answer?:
>
> A. 2
>
> B. 11

Comment: Why do you say "still"? How is it different if it's *not* a question? Can you give an example of *any* sentence where *which* has to be followed by *one*?

Comment: Sometimes there's more than one. *Out of the five following statements, **which two** are correct*?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which vs Which one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10084/which-vs-which-one)

Answer (score 1):

> When using the word "which" is it necessary to still use "one" after asking a question?

Generally no. You may optionally add "one" or not.

> do "which" and "which one" have the same meaning?

Generally yes. An exception could be if you are seeking multiple answers.

> "Sometimes there's more than one. Out of the five following statements, which two are correct?" – Smock

Answer (score 1):

(Not a teacher)
But, Yes, It's necessary ONE after WHICH when they're more than two options.
Example;  Your company gives you an opportunity to go to abroad, ticket and hotel expenses are free. But there's a limited countries  you can go for one of them America, Japan and India . The question is WHICH ONE DO YOU CHOOSE? (You can also placed "country" instead of "one")
But, when there's only two options  not necessary to but ONE after WHICH. But it's optional here..

Comment: Nice answer.  But consider this: the *is* in *X is* is only correct if X is singular.  So the *one* can be omitted - but you can always say *which one* to emphasize if the listener/reader might not be paying attention or you otherwise want to be really clear.